# espaco em branco entre um div e outro por causa dos campos ocultos

Tags: javascript

Quando temos campos ocultos entre campos que não são ocultos os espaços são considerados e o formulario fica com um visual ruim. queria saber se tem como tirar esses espaços em brancos entre os divs exibidos?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="lolkittens" />

    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<script language="javascript">

    function Mudarestado() {

          document.getElementById("ts1").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts2").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts3").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts4").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts5").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts6").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts7").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts8").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("bt1").style.visibility = "visible";

    }

    function Mudarestado2() {

          document.getElementById("ts11").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts12").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts13").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts14").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts15").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts16").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts17").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts18").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts19").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts20").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts21").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("ts22").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("bt2").style.visibility = "visible";

    }

</script>

<body>

<div style="width:100%; height: 200px; background-color: #8080FF;">


</div >

<div style="width:100%; height: 700px; background-color: gray;">

    <div><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div><input type="button" value="mudar estado" onclick="Mudarestado()"></div>

    <div id="ts1" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts2" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts3" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts4" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts5" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts6" ><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts7" ><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts8" ><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="bt1" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input value="mudar estado 2" type="button" onclick="Mudarestado2()"></div><br />
    <div id="ts11" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts12" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts13" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts14" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts15" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts16" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts17" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts18" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts19" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts20" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts21" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />
    <div id="ts22" style="visibility: hidden"><label>cargo</label><input type="text"></div><br />


</div>

<div style="width:100%; height: 200px; background-color: #FF8000;">
    <div><label>os 700 pixels acaba no fim da tarja laranja</label></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: vc nao ta escondendo os BRs, aí fica dificil.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira correta de fazer isso é usar classes de CSS, ou JavaScript associado à estrutura do DOM.

Estar a fazer dessa maneira, inline no `style` do HTML e funções no JavaScript com um comando para cada ID é um pesadelo. Verdade.

Deixo uma sugestão para repensares o código, e usares uma maneira que facilita a manutenção do código, e é mais escalável.

```js
function Mudarestado() {
     var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#campos > div');
     for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
         var el = inputs[i];
         el.classList.toggle('escondido');
     }
 }
```

```css
.escondido {
    display: none;
}

#campos > div {
 padding: 8px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="campos" style="width:100%; background-color: gray;">

    <div>
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts1" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts2" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts3" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts4" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts5" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts6">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts7">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts8">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <div id="ts11" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts12" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts13" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts14" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts15" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts16" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts17" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts18" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts19" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts20" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts21" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div id="ts22" class="escondido">
        <label>cargo</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="Mudar estado" onclick="Mudarestado()">
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nvzmLfat/1

## Notas:

- nesse exemplo não limpei todos os `style="xxx"` que tens inline no HTML. Isso deve ser feito com CSS externo ao HTML sempre que possível.
- como [o @bacco referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140762/espaco-em-branco-entre-um-div-e-outro-por-causa-dos-campos-ocultos/140767#comment291555_140762) esses `<br />` não estão a ser tratados pelo teu JavaScript. Na verdade nem os deves ter dessa maneira, pode usar CSS com `margin` ou `padding` para afastar os elementos uns dos outros e criar assim espaço entre elementos da página.

Answer (score 0):

Usa o display, com visibility o elemento vai continuar ocupando o espaço mesmo com o hidden

```
document.getElementById("bt1").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. A solução foi utilizar o display ao invés do visibility.